# Access an array of a class in another class without passing arguments in php

Tags: php, function, class, object, constructor

```
$mile= new mile();

  $get_sales_totals1=mysql_query("SELECT title,deadline FROM milestones where id=$id ");


  while($milestone = mysql_fetch_array($get_sales_totals1)){

    $mile->addne($milestone["deadline"],$milestone["title"]);
 }
```

I am trying to create an array of objects from database query.Above code is the main.php page and below is the page with classes.I created an array with deadline and title in each item of the array.

```
class mile {

    public $milearray;

public function __construct(){
    $this->milearray=array();

    }

    public function addne($deadline,$title){
     $ne->deadline=$deadline;
     $ne->title=$title;
     array_push($this->milearray,$ne);
    }

    public function extra(){

    //how to get milearray $this->milearray here

    }

}
```

Is it possible to get milearray in the function 'extra' in the same class without passing arguments.

OR

class compare is incomplete. I need to call milearray from class 'mile' inside class 'compare' without passing any arguments

```
    class compare{
   public daycomparearray;
    public function __construct(){
     $this->daycomparearray=array();

    }
    public function comparemile(){
     if($this->daycomparearray== milearrray->deadline)
    // how to get mile array here 
    }
    }
```

please help me....

Comment: You have to pass a `mile` object, because each object has its own `$milearray` property.

Comment: If you don't pass arguments, how do you know which objects to compare?

Comment: @Barmar could you please show how to pass mile object to class compare

Comment: The latest edit doesn't help much. What is `milearray->deadline` supposed to be? First, you're missing a `$`. Second, `$milearray` is an array, not an object, so you need to index it. Third, if you have multiple `mile` objects, which one's `$milearray` property should be used? `$this->daycomparearray` is also an array, how can you compare it just to a deadline? Do you want to get an array of all the deadlines in `$milearray` and compare that to `$this->daycomparearray`?

Comment: @Barmar Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [deadline] => 2019-02-01 [title] => Early Bird #1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [deadline] => 2019-03-01 [title] => Early Bird #2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [deadline] => 2019-03-31 [title] => Early Bird #3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [deadline] => 2019-04-26 [title] => Early Bird #4 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [deadline] => 2018-03-02 [title] => neenatrial ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [deadline] => 2017-03-01 [title] => neenatrial ) )                        this is how the miles array looks like

Comment: i am sorry . i am not an experienced person

Comment: Put the explanation of what you're trying to do in the question. Show some sample input and the desired result. Show how you use both of these classes.

Comment: i want to compare deadline in milestone array with date in the day compare array, if it matches display the title

Comment: Please do what I said before: Edit the question, and put all the details in there. You need about a paragraph of text and some more code showing the data and how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass arguments, otherwise the `compare` class won't know which objects to compare.

```
class compare{
    public function __construct(){

    }
    public function comparemile($mile1, $mile2){
        $array1 = $mile1->milearray;
        $array2 = $mile2->milearray;
        // code that compares $array1 and $array2
    }
}
```

If you can't pass arguments to the `comparemile` function, maybe it can be done with the constructor.

```
class compare{
    private $array1;
    private $array2;

    public function __construct($mile1, $mile2){
        $this->array1 = $mile1->milearray;
        $this->array2 = $mile2->milearray;

    }
    public function comparemile(){
        // code that compares $this->$array1 and $this->$array2
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible in my case since function comparemile is already called from different places without any arguments

Comment: How does it know what to compare if it's called without arguments? Are they provided in the constructor instead?

Comment: not in constructor.compare class is already there i am creating the mile class so that i can compare the elements of milearray with an array which is already in compare class

Comment: You need to edit the question to clarify how this class is intended to be used. Because you're putting so many restrictions that I can't understand how it can possibly work. How do you tell the `compare` class what to compare?

Answer (score -1):

You tried `self`? Like:

```py
public function extra(){
   $array = self::$milearray;
}
```

or making a session for `global` vars?

Comment: That's for static properties, not instance properties.

Comment: will print_r($array) prints the $milearray which is created in another function